# Conexao extendida do PDO não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Galera o netbeans não acusa nenhum erro, mas quando tento executar sempre dá erro no navegador, alguém sabe o que esta errado? podem me dizer como usar a conexão com pdo do metodo construtor da classe pai na classe filha?

**Classe Conexão:**

```
<?php

class Conexao {

    protected $Conecta;
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $dbname = "classificados";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";

    public function __construct() {

        try {

            $this->Conecta = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname}", "{$this->user}", "{$this->pass}");
            return $this->Conecta;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

**Classe Sessao**

    <?php

require_once "BD/Conexao.class.php";

class Sessao extends Conexao {

    private $verificaUser;

    public function setUsuario($email, $senha) {
        $this->verificaUser = parent::prepare("SELECT email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE cl_email = :email AND senha = :senha");
        $this->verificaUser->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $this->verificaUser->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
        $this->verificaUser->execute();
        return $this->verificaUser->rowCount();
    }

    public function getUsuario() {
        return $this->setUsuario();
    }

}

$teste = new Sessao;
$teste->setUsuario("fulano@bol.com", "123");
echo $teste->getUsuario();
```

**Erro:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexao::prepare() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php(24): Sessao->setUsuario('fulano@bol.com', '123') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on line 10
```

---

Lucas vi isso e me retornou esse erro:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Sessao::setUsuario(), called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on line 18 and
>   defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on
>   line 9
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Sessao::setUsuario(), called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on line 18 and
>   defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on
>   line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: senha in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/classificados/model/Sessao.class.php on line 12 0

Answer (score 0):

Tente deixar a classe conexão dessa forma; o método construtor não retorna valor, ele é apropriado para inicializar o objeto:

```
class Conexao extends PDO {

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $dbname = "classificados";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            parent::__construct("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname}", "{$this->user}", "{$this->pass}");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Na classe sessão você também vai precisar da conexão instanciada:

```
<?php

require_once "BD/Conexao.class.php";

class Sessao {

    private $verificaUser;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new Conexao();
    }

    public function setUsuario($email, $senha) {
        $this->verificaUser = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE cl_email = :email AND senha = :senha");
        $this->verificaUser->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $this->verificaUser->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
        $this->verificaUser->execute();
        return $this->verificaUser->rowCount();
    }

    public function getUsuario() {
        return $this->setUsuario();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas que classe PDO é essa da qual vou extender? não tenho essa classe.

Comment: É a mesma classe PDO interna do PHP que você está tentando instanciar no construtor: `$this->Conecta = new PDO(..`

Comment: Tente instanciar a conexão no construtor da classe Sessao, assim deve funcionar, conforme adicionei na resposta. Sugiro que dê uma estudada a mais em OO, pois mesmo que funcione, esse código ainda não está legal; e isso pode te dar dor de cabeça no futuro caso venha a criar sistemas com códigos assim.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro crie sua classe conexao, chamando `conexao.php`

```
<?php

class Conexao {

public static $instance;



private function __construct() {
    //
}


public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=seuBanco", "root", "suasenha", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Depois dentro de outra classe , faça o require e use a conexao , dessa forma.

```
 <?php

 require_once "conexao.php";

 class daoImport {



public function __construct() {

}

public function BuscarDadosCliente() {
    try {
        $linha = '';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM SuaTabela";
        $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance->prepare($sql);
        $execute = $p_sql->execute();
        if ($execute) {
            $linha = $p_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            print_r($linha);
        } else {
            print_r($p_sql->errorInfo());
            return 'ERRO... CONTATE O SUPORTE';
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "ERRRO" . $ex . "";
    }
  }

}
```